# Pyinstaller ModuleNotFoundError with self created package

Tags: python, pyinstaller, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to bundle my app into an executable file using PyInstaller using the command `pyinstaller --onefile --icon=icon.ico --windowed .\app.py`

Here's my hierarchy:

```
    .
├── app
├── __init__.py
├── Interfaces
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mainmenu.py
│   ├── login.py
│   .
    .
    .
├── app.py
```

The app.py does import a file from inside Interfaces package like this:

```
from Interfaces.mainmenu import MainUI
```

Howver as I launch the executable, this error occurs:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Interfaces'
```

---

As a side question, can I send the created exe to another computer and run it without having to install any extras?

Comment: Do you have a [spec file](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html) that you can share? I have it somehow working for my case, so there must be a difference. Also, do you get the same issue without the `--onefile` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it by explicitly importing "Interfaces" at the top of my `app.py` file:

```
import Interfaces
from Interfaces.mainmenu import MainUI
```